# Chosen Jquery Plugin - setting multiple values

Tags: jquery-chosen

I want to set multiple values like this:

$('#field-partners').val("1,7,9"); 
$('#field-partners').trigger("chosen:updated");
but it's not working..

I can only set one value like this :
$('#field-partners').val("1");
$('#field-partners').trigger("chosen:updated");
How can I set multiple values ?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out,this is the answer:

$('#field-partners').val(['7','9','11']); 
$('#field-partners').trigger("chosen:updated");